# Fluent NHibernate Dictionary<string, Entity> using 3 Tables

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to map a Many-To-Many table structure to a Dictionary where the key is in one table and the value is in another.

```
table Rows [Row_ID]

table Columns [Column_ID, Column_Name]

table Cells [Cell_ID, Row_ID, Column_Id, Cell_Value]

public class Row {
    public Row() {
        this.Cells = new Dictionary<string, Cell>();
    }

    public virtual long Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual IDictionary<string, Cell> Cells { get; set; }
}

public class RowMap : ClassMap<Row> {
    public RowMap() {
        Table("Rows");
        Id(m => m.Id, "Row_Id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        HasManyToMany<Column>(m => m.Cells).Table("Cells")
            .ParentKeyColumn("Row_Id").ChildKeyColumn("Column_Id")
            .AsMap<string>("Column_Name").Inverse().Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class Column {
    public virtual long Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ColumnMap : ClassMap<Column> {
    public ColumnMap() {
        Table("Columns");
        Id(m => m.Id, "Column_Id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(m => m.Name, "Column_Name").Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class Cell {
    public virtual long Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual Column Column { get; set; }

    public virtual Row Row { get; set; }
}

public class CellMap : ClassMap<Cell> {
    public CellMap() {
        Id(m => m.Id, "Cell_Id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(m => m.Value, "Cell_Value").Not.Nullable();
        References(m => m.Column, "Column_Id");
        References(m => m.Row, "Row_Id");
    }
}
```

Everything compiles correctly but when I try to access the Cells collection I get the following error:

```
could not initialize a collection: [Sandbox.Row.Cells#1][SQL: SELECT cells0_.Row_Id as
Row1_1_, cells0_.Column_Id as Column2_1_, cells0_.Column_Name as Column3_1_,
column1_.Column_Id as Column1_8_0_, column1_.Column_Name as Column2_8_0_ FROM Cells
cells0_ left outer join Columns column1_ on cells0_.Column_Id=column1_.Column_Id WHERE
cells0_.Row_Id=?]
```

After reviewing the error message I see that the query is trying to access the key "Column_Name" as a field in the Cells table instead of the Columns table.

Any ideas on how I can tell NHibernate to map this to the correct table or is what I am trying to do not possible?

Comment: Have you tried Column.Name? I've never mapped using a Dictionary, seems interesting.

Comment: I have tried changing the AsMap<string>("Column_Name") to AsMap<string>(index => index.Name) but all it did was change the query to reference "Name" instead of "Column_Name" on the Cells table.

Comment: Could you try Column.Name? Using the class and attribute names is somewhat a convention with Fluent

Comment: I am not sure that I am following you. Perhaps an example of what you are talking about would help.

Comment: Instead of `.AsMap<string>("Column_Name").Inverse().Cascade.All();` try `.AsMap<string>("Column.Name").Inverse().Cascade.All();`

Comment: I just gave that a shot and got the same error. It tried to do this: cells0_.Column.Name

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me Andre. I ended up taking Firo's suggestion but I do appreciate your assistance.

Comment: You are most welcome. I was out of clues, actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the columns table is never mentioned in the hasmanytomany (intermediate table: Cells, EntityTable of Cells: Cells) hence it can't be referenced at all. The only option i see at the moment is to change the dictionary to start with.

```
public virtual IDictionary<Column, Cell> Cells { get; private set; }

HasMany(m => m.Cells)
    .Table("Cells")
    .KeyColumn("Row_Id")
    .AsEntityMap("Column_id")
    .Inverse().Cascade.All();
```

you could hold a global Dictionary from column.Name to column instance to save the roundtrips or denormalize the columnname into the cells table.

Comment: I ended up adding a Table entity and referenced the Columns as a Dictinary<string, Column> collection and then reference the columns using this collection. (i.e. table.Rows[0].Cells[table.Columns["ColumnName"]].Value) Not exactly what I was looking for but it works and that is what matters. Would still love to do it the other way but I am not going to drive myself crazy trying to figure it out. Thank you for the help!